# Spring Scheduled task: Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread

Tags: spring, asynchronous, cron, request

I am writing a project with Spring Boot 1.5.8.
I have some Entity classes which are generated and contain bean (for Example FooBean) which only exists in request scope. What is important: i am not able to change that part of code. So assume that i have an Entty:

```
@Enitty
public class FooEntity{
    @Transient protected FooBean fooBean;
}
```

and FooBean implementation:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class FooBean {

    ...
}
```

I also have some part of code where i have method which should be runned by Spring CRON:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/2 * * * ?")
@Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
void scheduledTask() {
    ...
}
```

What's important: in that scheduledTask i am saving some instances of FooEntity to DB. 
And of course: When i try to invoke repository.saveAll() Spring is throwing an exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.fooBean ': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread;
```

Is there any possibility to resolve that problem? How can I override this scoped bean so it will be available in not-request scope?

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm writing a little bit later :) but you can create your own instance of this bean.
In spring boot you can simply create your own singleton instance of the bean like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ApiConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public FooBean fooBean(){
       return new FooBean();
    }
}
```

In case your bean has some dependencies in constructor (constructor autowired) which has to be autowired you can simply put those beans in method params and spring will provide it for you like this:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public FooBean fooBean(BeanToAutowire myBean){
   return new FooBean(myBean);
}
```

In case your bean has no constructor autowired dependencies but annotation autowired (using @Autowired) you can simple do it like this:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public FooBean fooBean(AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory){
   FooBean bean = new FooBean(myBean);
   beanFactory.autowireBean(bean); // here spring will autowire all dependencies for you
   return bean;
}
```

It is not the most elegant way to do it but it works. Side effect is that there will be two instances of FooBean in app context but spring will use your instance because you set this instance as primary using @Primary annotation. Only beans which use Autowired annotation together with qualifier annotation can choose which instance of FooBean will be autowired.